# PHP - Show/hide a picture based on date

Tags: php

I want to show a GIF image based on a table's `date` field.

Like:

```
$dt = $row['PicDate']; // date is 2016-05-04 10:57:51

if($dt > strtotime('-30 days')){
    echo '<img src="image/new.gif">';
}
```

But the problem is, the image is not showing.

What am I to do ?

Comment: Is that the correct way to use strtotime?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$dt` is a "date/time" string. To compare timestamps you should convert `$dt` with `strtotime` function:

```
$dt = $row['PicDate']; // date is 2016-05-04 10:57:51

if (strtotime($dt) > strtotime('-30 days')) {
    echo '<img src="image/new.gif">';
}
```